# ignoring backslash for checking or printing

Tags: java, system.out

I have string like `"hello\nworld"` and if i use

> `System.out.println(string);`

it will out put like:

> hello
> world

Or if i use

> `System.out.printf(string);`

it will out put: helloworld 
but i want java method that output exactly like it:`hello\nworld`
means i want ignore backslash character like newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use apache commons [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava%28java.lang.String%29).

```
System.out.println("String s = \""
    + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(string)
    + "\";");
```

A tab character `"\t"` is then replaced with a backslash and a `t`. *As others said, the String representations represents some special characters like linefeed/newline with `\n`.*

The above would be fit for generating Java source code or so.

Comment: what is StringEscapeUtils?

Comment: @Erfan13 it is part of [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/). It is placed in `org.apache.commons.lang3` package. [Here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) is download page.

Comment: StringEscapeUtils is a small jewel. To generate JavaScript with escapes (backslashes), to replace HTML entities like `&ccirc;` with their true characters `ĉ`, and such.

Answer (score 3):

Then you need to construct your String as

```
String s = "hello\\nworld";
```

to escape the backslash.

Comment: If you do not escape the backslash, you'd need to format the String yourself, replacing "\n" with "\\n" in order to display it. String.replaceAll() can be used for it.

Comment: i cant do this. String was made automatically

Answer (score 0):

Just change your string to `String s = "hello\\nworld";`

You can also refer here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: i cant do this. String made automatically!

Answer (score 0):

`\` is special character in String. It can be used to:

- create special characters that normally can't be written like LF (line fead -> `\n`), CR (Carriage return -> `\r`), tabulator -> `\t`
- escape other characters that have special meaning in String, for instance to print `"` you need to escape it first `\"` and in your case to be able to print `\` you need to escape it with other backslash like `"\\"`.